# maya makePaintable attribute

Tags: maya

stupid question but I m having an issue with that.
Can you make more than 1 attribute paintable on the same shape ?

I am adding 3 double array attributes for testing purpose and I make them paintable trough a loop while adding them.

When I do that, I can t paint them through my test and to verify that i tried painting it via right click on the mesh -> paint -> mesh and I only see the usual paintable attributes + the first one I defined...

Is there anything specific to do to declare more than 1 attributes paintable ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I found out why it wasn't working. The documentation for makePaintable is wrong ...

cmds.makePaintable('node','attribute') like shown in the documentation doesn't work. Instead, you have to do cmds.makePaintable('nodeType','attribute') and your mesh has to be selected (I suppose as you don't specify it in the command)

It is now working.